# Attaining uniqueness through 3 columns in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a database schema in which a ResourceA can only be booked once at DateX and HourY.

So the rows would be like:

1. ResourceA/DateX/HourY
2. ResourceB/DateX/HourY
3. ResourceA/DateY/HourY

But not the same three-column tuple.

How can I do that using Django models?

How would the corresponding forms be created?

I couldn't find what I needed in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) Meta option:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
     resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
     date = models.DateField()
     hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

     class Meta:
         unique_together = ('resource', 'date', 'hour')
```